# How to write to a File and add "'s and )'s

Tags: java, file, class, bufferedwriter, buffered

I'm writing to a file using BufferedWriter and when I enter this code

```
bfW.write("System.out.println("YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED");");
```

and it gives me this error:

```
 File_writer.java:93: error: ';' expected                  
 bfW.write("System.out.println("YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED");");
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the double-quotes:

```
bfW.write("System.out.println(\"YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED\");");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bfW.write("System.out.println(\"YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED\");");
```

So if you want to define a `String` which contains `""`, you do it in this way:

```
String s = "I am a string with \"\"";
```

s will be:

```
I am a string with ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write what to the file? "YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED"?

Then the code should be:

```
bfW.write("YOUR NEW PROGRAM IS COMPLETED");
```

Comment: that's not what OP asked. As the title says : *How to write to a File and add "'s and )'s*, OP wants to know how to write " or ) characters